# Android studio could not detect handheld device IC-600S

Tags: android, handhelddevice

I want to develop an android app for handheld device "IC-600S" but android studio could not detect this device.
the device is already appears on windows device manager but when I try to debug the project android studio shows the message "no USB devices or running emulators".
developer options enabled, usb cable is OK.
is there something missing?
device 
[link](https://itos.es/en/mobility/ic-600s/).

Comment: Did you enable USB debugging in your device?

Comment: I solved the problem by copying the hardware ids for the device and googling, I found multiple drivers one of them solved the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by copying the hardware ids for the device and googling, I found multiple drivers one of them solved the problem.